# Object dispose in IDisposable class

Tags: c#, dispose

I am just inheriting IDisposable interface in my class like this.

```
public class Program3:IDisposable
{

}
```

When I am creating an instance to the above class, I want to dispose the object manually or the object disposed by it automatically?

Note : I am not using Dispose method explicitly to dispose the object

Comment: Why are you implementing it in the first place? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement IDisposable interface methods:

```
 public void Dispose()
    {
        // Clear all unmanaged resources
    }
```

Whenever you then instantiate your object you should do it inside a using statement

```
using(Program3 p3 = new Program3())
{
//do your job
} // here the p3.Dispose gets called
```

It is important to note that the point of Dispose is to free unmanaged resources. What you get in. Net is already managed, so only if you are implementing something of your own should you use IDisposable.